# How to find oracle error codes that could result from a connection error?

Tags: oracle, ora-12560

I would like to handle an OracleException thrown when my network/database connection is interrupted, where can I find out what error codes I might can receive?

I guess since we are talking about a connection interruption these would be technically TNS errors such as ORA-12560 "TNS:protocol adapter error." But I have noticed a couple others depending on where exactly the connection is lost and would like to get a full list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Oracle Database Error Messages 11g Release 1 (11.1)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/toc.htm). And here are the [search results for TNS errors](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db111/search?remark=quick_search&word=TNS&partno=b28278).

Comment: 987 results!  Wow, those guys at oracle sure love to make things easy

Answer (score 1):

There's a full list here:
http://ora-code.com

But note that some of them, like "TNS:protocol adapter error", can actually mean many different things.

Comment: Ugh, That only makes my problem MORE difficult not less.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORA-12154 TNS:could not resolve service name"
ORA-12203 TNS:unable to connect to destination"
ORA-12500 TNS:listener failed to start a dedicated server process"
ORA-12545 TNS:name lookup failure"
ORA-12560 TNS:protocol adapter error"
```